# dlsym function pointer dereferenced is 0

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I am having issues where all android phones are returning a pointer to the function `_zn7android14androidruntime7mjavavme` whenever I call `dlsym` on `/system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so`, but for some of the phones, de-referencing this function is returning `0`, vs the correct address location of the code to import the JVM. What could be the reason behind this issue?

```
   addr = dlsym(lib, _zn7android14androidruntime7mjavavme);
   if (*addr == 0){
       goto fail;
   }

fail:
    //cleanup
```

I am wondering if I need to pass in more RTLD flags to the dlopen, but I am not sure, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `dlerror` would be a good source of information. (After unsuccessful `dlopen`/`dlsym`.)

Comment: so I did that, and it gave me ```Symbol not found: android_log_print```, which does not make any sense.

Comment: Guess it was after `dlopen`, not after `dlsym`.

Comment: so ```dlopen``` shouldn't be an issue since if it was, it would be returning NULL, but it is NOT

Comment: I also just confirmed, so that error I was getting with android_log_print is a previous error that was just not cleaned up, so the dlopen and dlsym all returned NO errors. However, when I did a memory dump of the address returned, it is ALL NULL. What could be the reason behind that

Comment: Would you mind quoting the actual code? (What you have quoted so far is syntactically invalid.)

Comment: I cannot unfortunately since its on a different system, and the code I provided above is just pseudocode. I can tell you up front that the code I have works on SOME phones, but not all of them.